# Why do Objective-c protocols adopt other protocols?

Tags: objective-c, ios, protocols, nsobject

I've seen Objective-c protocols defined in the following way:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <SomeOtherProtocol>
// ...
@end
```

**Why do protocols adopt other protocols?**  I'm especially curious why a protocol would adopt the `NSObject` protocol.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is simply the same concept as inheritance for classes.
If a protocol adopt another protocol, it "inherits" the declared methods of this adopted protocol.

The `NSObject` protocol especially declares methods such as `respondsToSelector:`. So this is especially useful if you declare a `@protocol` that have `@optional` methods, because when you will then call methods on objects conforming this protocol, you will need to check if the object responds to the method before calling it if this method is optional.

---

```
@protocol SomeProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)requiredMethod;
@optional
-(void)optionalMethod;
@end

@interface SomeObject : NSObject
-(void)testMyDelegate;
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<SomeProtocol> myDelegate;
@end
```

---

```
@implementation SomeObject
@synthesize myDelegate

-(void)testMyDelegate {
    // Here you can call requiredMethod without any checking because it is a required (non-optional) method
    [self.myDelegate requiredMethod];

    // But as "optionalMethod" is @optional, you have to check if myDelegate implements this method before calling it!
    if ([myDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(optionalMethod)]) {
        // And only call it if it is implemented by the receiver
        [myDelegate optionalMethod];
    }
}
@end
```

**You will only be able to call `respondsToSelector` on myDelegate if `myDelegate` is declared as a type that implements `respondsToSelector`** (otherwise you will have some warnings). That's why the `<SomeProtocol>` protocol needs to adopt itself the `<NSObject>` protocol, which itself declares this method.

You may think of `id<SomeProtocol>` as "any object, whatever its type (`id`), it just has to implement the methods declared in `SomeProtocol`, including the methods declared in the parent protocol `NSObject`. So it can be an object of any type but **because `SomeProtocol` adopts the `NSObject` protocol itself, it is guaranteed that you are allowed to call `respondsToSelector` on this object, allowing you to check if the object implements a given method before calling it if it is optional**.

---

*Note that you may also not make `SomeProtocol` adopt the `NSObject` protocol and instead declare your variable as `id<SomeProtocol,NSObject> myDelegate` so that you can still call `respondsToSelector:`. But if you do that you will need to declare all your variables this way everywhere you use this protocol... So this is much more logical to make `SomeProtocol` directly adopt the `NSObject` protocol ;)*

Comment: Note that having the original protocol conform to `NSObject` is not strictly necessary in order to avoid warnings. Instead of using `id<SomeProtocol> myDelegate`, use `NSObject<SomeProtocol> *myDelegate`.

Comment: Yes, this can be a solution too. But it inserts then a dependency on types (even if this is unlikely to occur, some may use NSProxy or whatever; I agree this is uncommon and rare but anyway) so it kinda violates the obcuration principle of OOP. If there is no reason to force the user to use a class that explicitly inherits NSObject, but instead you only need that is implements some given methods, why force it... the right approach is then to use the `NSObject` protocol and the `id<NSObject>` type, not the NSObject type, to keep weak links between types and avoid strong typing.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance...................

Comment: Interface Inheritance, more precisely.